# Boost asio - endpoint документация

Tags: asio, boost.asio

Подскажите пожалуйста, как пользоваться документацией Boost Asio ?

Вот есть к примеру функция:

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint my_endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), 80);
```

Как понять, что она должна принимать на вход ?

Вот я иду в документацию:  https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/endpoint.html

Вот я смотрю на эту страницу и ничего толкового не вижу, я не вижу не описание функции, ни какие аргументы она принимает, ни что они значат.

Вот к примеру я меняю v4 на v6:

boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint my_endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4, 80);

И уже ошибка: "Отсутствуют экземпляры конструктора."
А откуда я знаю, что endpoint  ожидает к себе на вход ?

ПРИЧЕМ на странице: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference.html
Вообще нет упоминания функции "read_some" - а в коде она без проблем компилируется.

Comment: Ну это же конструктор, смотрите описание конструктора https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__basic_endpoint/basic_endpoint/overload2.html. `read_some` — функция-член у `basic_stream_socket`, у него и смотрите https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/read_some.html.

Comment: @tocic, Спасибо. А почему на этой странице нет этого read_some ? https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference.html

Comment: На ней нет функций-членов, а есть в основном классы и свободные функции. То есть это не страница всех возможных идентификаторов из библиотеки, как, возможно, вы думали.